# Redirecting a domain to another that hosts a wordpress site, getting database errors

Tags: wordpress, redirect, apache2

Originally I had `mydomain.com.au`, but then I let it expire as I cancelled my `abn`. After that I started using `mydomain.info` instead to host my WordPress site. Recently I had my `abn` re-instated so I have `mydomain.com.au` back again finally.

I decided to do a permanent redirect from mydomain.com.au to mydomain.info, and I put this in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.au.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@email.com
    ServerName mydomain.com.au
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.mydomain.info/
</VirtualHost>
```

It looks the same in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.au.conf` also.

I reloaded `apache2` without error and now I get this error when I try to access `www.mydomain.com.au` either locally or from an `external IP`:

> **Database Error**
>
> **Error establishing a database connection**

I decided to test whether the redirect was working by putting a dummy html file in `/var/www/mydomain.com.au`. I reloaded `apache2` and tried `mydomain.com.au` again. Still getting the database error.

So now i'm thinking it's a problem with WordPress. **Does WordPress not allow you to do this kind of thing?**

Comment: Not unless you edit the `wp-config.php` file to reflect these changes. Simple Apache redirects wont work

Comment: wp-config.php contains database settings, salts etc. I don't see anything in there relating to this.

Comment: What about `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and `PATH_CURRENT_SITE` ? Read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs . Should help you fix

Comment: I'm not trying to move the website. I'm pointing another domain to it as well. Furthermore those settings are not in wp-config.php. Don't know what file you are actually referring to. It says up there in my question quite clearly that I'm trying to point two domains to one wordpress install not that I'm trying to move from one domain to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect was set up incorrectly. It was working for domain.com.au but not for www.domain.com.au. It needs to be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@email.com
    ServerName domain.com.au
    ServerAlias www.domain.com.au
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.domain.info/
</VirtualHost>
```